# Can not get rid of: Unsafe member access fs.existsSync on an any value in plugin/index.js

Tags: cypress

I have the following code in the index.js plugin file. It basically works, but the eslint is complaining:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  
  on('task', {
    readFile(filename) {
      if (fs.existsSync(filename)) {
        return fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8');
      }
      return null;
    },
  });
};
```

If I look at my editor I see this:
[EsLint complains: Unsafe member access .existsSync on an any value.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5JCa.png)

> Unsafe member access .exports on an any value.

and

> Unsafe member access .readFileSync on an any value.

The only way I can get rid of it is with:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong

```
import * as fs from 'fs'
```

try

```js
import fs from 'fs'
```

But it looks like a typescript type definition problem, you can try adding the [node types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/node) package

```js
npm install --save @types/node
```

and make sure you have this in `tsconfig.json`

```js
"compilerOptions": {
  "typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks.The first suggestion is actually recommended by eslint and it complains if you do it just the simple way you suggested. So far I had no luck with the npm installation and the tsconfig modification.